# Meaning of red cross icon next to Geoprocessing tool/model?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, modelbuilder, arctoolbox

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

When I double-click on the toolbox command line, it is not working and appears as a red cross symbol in command tool icon.

So please, what can I do?

Comment: welcome to gis.stackexchange
You are going to have to be specific as to what tool you are trying to use, also, if a tool is associated with a particular extension, ensure that you have the extension toggle on in the Customize, Extensions menu

Answer (score 2):

If the extension were installed but not enabled you'd see a padlock symbol, not a red cross. If a model or script tool has lost its reference you would see such a symbol and you'd need to fix the reference to the tool/model location. See the 10.2 Desktop Help article: [Repairing a model](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000018000000)